# Как в modx в на банер повесить ссылку?

Tags: modx

Как в modx в на банер повесить ссылку? у меня в 
Параметры (TV) задан путь к картинке теперь нужно чтобы эта картинка когда на неё нажимаеш делала переход на другую страницу.
Как это сделать  помогите плз... очень надо сделать сегодня.

Comment: Покажите код шаблона, где вставляется баннер.

Comment: modx evo,revo? где вообще вы выводите баннер в шаблоне или в чанке? Ссылка тоже из TV или только картинка. Если сложно объяснить сделайте скриншот админки там где у вас баннер и там где он выводится и вам обязательно помогут. А то как то вообще информации ноль.

Comment: спасибо я уже разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить новое TV для ссылки, добавить разрешение для шаблона, в верстке указать ссылку на ваш TV пример

```html
<a href="[[+tv.название тв поля с ссылкой]]"><img scr="[[+ссылка на картинку]]"></a>
```

А если выводите через pdoResources не забудьте указать параметр &includeContent=`1`